# Select2 multiple rails form value format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jquery-select2

I'm using [Select2 3.5.2](https://github.com/select2/select2/tree/3.5.2) with a Rails 2.3 app using Postgres and have a form field with `multiple: true`

```
$('.select2').select2()

<%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name, class: 'select2', multiple: true, %>
```

When saving, the database is populated with (for example):

```
--- 
- ""
- "4"
- "7"
```

But when editing the form, the values do not populate the select2. I have tried passing multiple kinds of values into the select to try to populate it, but no luck. I've tried:

```
value: "--- \n- ""\n- "4"\n- "7""
value: 4,7
value: [4,7]
value: ['4', '7']
value: "[\"4\", \"7\"]"
```

What value does it expect so that it can be populated with existing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I was putting the value in the wrong place. Instead of:

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.all, :id, :name, class: 'select2', multiple: true, value: [1] %>
```

I needed:

```
<%= f.select :user_ids, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :name, params[:user_ids] || [1,2]), class: 'select2', multiple: true %>
```

At least, that worked for me.